# Redmine Project Repository 404 Error

Tags: git, redmine

I am configuring redmine to pull commit histories from an associated git repository.  I have set up a local mirror.  I have the path to the mirror defined in the project settings >> repository tab.  But when I browse to the project's repository tab I get:

> 404
>
> The entry or revision was not found in the repository.

The production log shows:

```
Started GET "/projects/allsaints/repository" for 108.58.11.138 at 2013-03-24 17:51:27 -0400
Processing by RepositoriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"allsaints"}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT MAX(`settings`.`updated_on`) AS max_id FROM `settings` 
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser') AND `users`.`id` = 1 AND (users.status = 1) LIMIT 1[0m
  Current user: Shawn (id=1)
  [1m[35mProject Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`identifier` = 'allsaints' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mRepository Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `repositories`.* FROM `repositories` WHERE `repositories`.`project_id` = 3 AND (is_default = 1) LIMIT 1[0m
Shelling out: '/usr/local/git/bin/git' '--git-dir' '/Library/WebServer/Sites/redmine2/extra/repositories/allsaints.git/' '-c' 'core.quotepath=false' '-c' 'log.decorate=no' 'log' '--no-color' '--encoding=UTF-8' '--date=iso' '--pretty=fuller' '--no-merges' '-n' '1'
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (0.7ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE `repositories` SET `root_url` = '/Library/WebServer/Sites/redmine2/extra/repositories/allsaints.git/', `extra_info` = '---\nextra_report_last_commit: \'0\'\n' WHERE `repositories`.`type` IN ('Repository::Git') AND `repositories`.`id` = 21[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  COMMIT
Shelling out: '/usr/local/git/bin/git' '--git-dir' '/Library/WebServer/Sites/redmine2/extra/repositories/allsaints.git/' '-c' 'core.quotepath=false' '-c' 'log.decorate=no' 'branch' '--no-color' '--verbose' '--no-abbrev'
  [1m[36mEnabledModule Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT name FROM `enabled_modules` WHERE `enabled_modules`.`project_id` = 3[0m
Shelling out: '/usr/local/git/bin/git' '--git-dir' '/Library/WebServer/Sites/redmine2/extra/repositories/allsaints.git/' '-c' 'core.quotepath=false' '-c' 'log.decorate=no' 'ls-tree' '-l' 'HEAD:'
  Rendered common/error.html.erb within layouts/base (0.3ms)
  [1m[35mUserPreference Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT `user_preferences`.* FROM `user_preferences` WHERE `user_preferences`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `members`.`id` AS t0_r0, `members`.`user_id` AS t0_r1, `members`.`project_id` AS t0_r2, `members`.`created_on` AS t0_r3, `members`.`mail_notification` AS t0_r4, `projects`.`id` AS t1_r0, `projects`.`name` AS t1_r1, `projects`.`description` AS t1_r2, `projects`.`homepage` AS t1_r3, `projects`.`is_public` AS t1_r4, `projects`.`parent_id` AS t1_r5, `projects`.`created_on` AS t1_r6, `projects`.`updated_on` AS t1_r7, `projects`.`identifier` AS t1_r8, `projects`.`status` AS t1_r9, `projects`.`lft` AS t1_r10, `projects`.`rgt` AS t1_r11, `roles`.`id` AS t2_r0, `roles`.`name` AS t2_r1, `roles`.`position` AS t2_r2, `roles`.`assignable` AS t2_r3, `roles`.`builtin` AS t2_r4, `roles`.`permissions` AS t2_r5, `roles`.`issues_visibility` AS t2_r6 FROM `members` LEFT OUTER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `members`.`project_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_roles` ON `member_roles`.`member_id` = `members`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `member_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `members`.`user_id` = 1 AND (projects.status<>9) ORDER BY projects.name[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `versions`.`id`) FROM `versions` LEFT OUTER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `versions`.`project_id` WHERE (projects.id = 3 OR (projects.status <> 9 AND ( versions.sharing = 'system' OR (projects.lft >= 1 AND projects.rgt <= 2 AND versions.sharing = 'tree') OR (projects.lft < 1 AND projects.rgt > 2 AND versions.sharing IN ('hierarchy', 'descendants')) OR (projects.lft > 1 AND projects.rgt < 2 AND versions.sharing = 'hierarchy'))))
  [1m[36mWiki Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `wikis`.* FROM `wikis` WHERE `wikis`.`project_id` = 3 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `boards` WHERE `boards`.`project_id` = 3
Completed 404 Not Found in 108ms (Views: 40.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

My understanding is that one can verify which user redmine is running as by checking the owner of production.log.  Taking any of these Shelling out: entries, stripping the single quotes and running the resulting command as as that user results in proper output.

So why the 404 error?

Comment: ./script/rails runner "Repository.fetch_changesets" -e production
also runs - the only output is the warning on session secrets that is apparently a known rails bug and a warning about iconv deprecation in the activesupport gem

Comment: Redmine version                          2.1.4.stable
  Ruby version                             1.9.3 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0)
  Rails version                            3.2.8

Comment: Upgraded: Redmine version 2.2.4.stable, Ruby version                             1.9.3 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0), Rails version 3.2.13.  Now the users that have committed to the repo list on the Settings>>Repositories>>Users page.  Still 404 on the Repositories tab

Comment: First real clue: _fatal: failed to read object 51a1f7d5c63e390d7846b8eb993854254cd5a0fe: Permission denied_ in the apache log, which is a git error.  Still puzzling because both the owner of the production.log file and www user can execute a git log inside the repo...

Answer (score 2):

This was indeed a permissions problem.  Passenger has [user switching](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerUserSwitching) enabled by default so that the rails application runs the owner of `config/environment.rb`. What tripped me up was the application did not inherit all the group memberships of that user but rather the group by default is explicitly set to the primary group of that user.  I am using group permissions for access to these files.  Inserting a [PassengerGroup](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengergroup_lt_group_name_gt) directive into the Virtual Host block for this site that explicitly set the proper group resolved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, it is the permission issue.
You should move the repository to another location such as /tmp/xxx.git I gave full permission to repository in my home directory, but I got error because redmine can not read my home directory.